# Android BLE notifications are irregular

Tags: android, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

My java code runs on Quest 2 (Android 12.0 and OS version 56) and subscribes to the gatt cadence characteristic of a cadence sensor.

The Cadence notifications typically arrive once per second. However some notifications can take up to 5 seconds to arrive. In that case all 5 notifications arrive at once. Is this typical on Android devices? I don't recall seeing this problem with my IOS code.

Comment: No this is not typical. You probably have a bad radio environment, bluetooth antenna, bluetooth chip or similar. You could try using a generic BLE debug app such as nRF Connect. Try to subscribe for notifications. If they are lagging there as well, there is no problem with your code at least running in your Android app.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I don't see any delays with the nRF Connect app. However that app is running on IOS. My app is running on Quest 2. I have been unable to find a BLE monitoring app for Quest 2.

Comment: Are you able to install apps via thei apk files on your Quest 2? The [Github Repo](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Connect/releases) for nRF Connect allows you to download the releases as well

Comment: Thank you Michael. I was able to install and run nRF Connect this way. I'm seeing the same irregularity with nRF Connect as with my program.  It seems the issue is with the Quest 2 OS. Thanks again Emil and Michael!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the much appreciated assistance of Emil and Michael Kotzjan, I was able to run nRF Connect on the Quest 2.

The cadence notifications received by nRF Connect were as irregular as with my app.

However, when running nRF Connect on IOS (IPhone 13), all cadence notifications came in regularly. That is to say, each notification came in approximately one second after the previous one.

It appears that the problem is with the Quest 2. I've submitted a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with your results, let's hope they fix this bug for you :)